# solving 2 variable equation with 4 unknown variable and having total 4 equation find value of a b c d

Tags: linear-algebra

a+b = 110
a+c = 130
c+d = 160
b+d = 140
How to solve this equation without hit and trial method
can we get the value of a b c d?

Comment: @KKT There is no $a+d$ value. This system is underdetermined. EG We can get to $ a+b+c+d$ in 2 ways.

Comment: can we solve individual value of all variable or not??

Comment: Put any value of $a$, you will get values for $b,c,d$. If you put another value, you will get another set of values of $b,c,d$ and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve the system systematically you could try to reduce the number of variables. Let's try to get rid of $d$ first. By using the last equation we get $d=140-b$ which allows us to replace any $d$ by $140-b$.

Let's now get rid of $c$: For that we use the second equation which gives $c=130-a$. To get rid of $b$ we use the first equation and arrive at $b=110-a$.

If we now want to get rid of $b$ as well (meaning we are trying to describe all other variables by means of a) we can plug in the last result in the first result we had to get $d=140-b = 140-(110-a) = a+30$. We have now
$$d=a+30$$
$$c=130-a$$
$$b=110-a$$

And from that you can see that we won't get one single solution but infinitely many solutions. For any choice of a value $a$ we get a solution $(a,b,c,d)$ by using these last three equations.

Mathematically speaking the system of equations is underdetermined and therefore admits infinitely many solutions.

Comment: please avoid answering no effort questions

Comment: OP seems to have very fundamental problems with the topic - how is he/she supposed to show effort if he doesn't even know and understand the fundamentals? 
I don't get why helping people is not encouraged on this site...